# How to pass the data to next View via Segue in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am developing in Swift.

And the following picture is my storyboard.

[image]

There has a **Main view**. The **Main view** will change the view to the **Scan view** and also pass the data to the **`Scan view`** when press the **Scan (Right Bar button item)**.

And the **identifier** of the **StoryBoard Segue** is **ScanView**

I use the following code to pass the data from **Main** to the **Scan**

When press the **Scan (Right Bar button item)**.

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ScanView", sender: self)
```

And pass the data to the next view

```
//prepare jumping to next page
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier=="ScanView"){
        let desViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ScanViewController
        desViewController.myCenteralManager = myCenteralManager
    }
}
```

And it will crash at `let desViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ScanViewController` and show the error like the following :

```
Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x3960e0a8) to 'BLEConnect.ViewController' (0x5514c).
```

Can someone teach me how to solve the issue ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear; you tried to force cast a UINaigationController as a ScanViewController. You can either embed your main view controller in the navigation controller rather than the scan view, otherwise you need to access the scan view controller from the ViewControllers property of the navigation controller. I also don't like the looks of that segue from scan view back to main view. You should use an unwind segue or if you embed main view controller in the navigation controller then the back button will be there by default

Answer (score 1):

The error message are pretty clear, you try to get `segue.destinationViewController` as `ScanViewController` while in fact it is a navigation controller. You need to get the navigation controller first and then use its `topViewController` property to get your targeted view controller.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) 
{ 
    if (segue.identifier=="ScanView") {
        if let navController: UINavigationController = segue.destinationViewController as? UINavigationController {
            if let desViewController: ScanViewController = navController.topViewController as? ScanViewController {
                desViewController.myCenteralManager = myCenteralManager
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `NavigationController` is (probably) in the wrong place in Interface Builder. Right now, when you segue, you are going to the `UINavigationController` and not the `ScanViewController` like you expect. This is why the cast fails, because you are trying to force the `UINavigationController` to be a `ScanViewController`.

To fix this, you should place your `MainViewController` in the `UINavigationController` and then segue straight to your `ScanViewController`.

[This guide](https://www.appcoda.com/use-storyboards-to-build-navigation-controller-and-table-view/) shows exactly how you can use Interface Builder, UINavigationController, and segues to achieve what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed your *navigation controller* to the **main ViewController** and perform a segue as you have done above. That should solve the problem.

The error message is displayed because you have type casted **Navigation Controller** instead of **Scan ViewController** .